# pixijs retexturing a bullet

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I am building a shooter game using html5, canvas, javascript - pixijs. Below is the bullet code. It will skin a bullet - it is limited to only allow 20 bullets max on the screen to save resources.

The bullets then get recycled in a reset function. Its working great on the whole. The problem now though - is I have 2 bullet types - standard and missile. Essentially when the bullet gets reset - I need to ensure its skinned properly. I've tried empting the crossection array and rebuilding it - but its almost as if it just clones the bullet and I end up with more objects.

```
var TestProjectileVector = (function (_super) {
    __extends(TestProjectileVector, _super);
    function TestProjectileVector(parentScene, x, y, z, localScale, velocity, gravity, vector, projectiletype) {
        if (typeof x === "undefined") { x = 0; }
        if (typeof y === "undefined") { y = 0; }
        if (typeof z === "undefined") { z = 0; }
        if (typeof localScale === "undefined") { localScale = 1; }
        if (typeof velocity === "undefined") { velocity = 100; }
        if (typeof gravity === "undefined") { gravity = 0; }
        if (typeof vector === "undefined") { vector = MathK.Vector3.zero; }
        if (typeof projectiletype === "undefined") { projectiletype = "bullet"; }
        _super.call(this, parentScene, x, y, z, .13);
        this.verticalAngle = 0;
        this.horizontalAngle = 0;
        this.drag = .99;
        this.isDead = false;
        this.isRebounding = false;
        this.doCollisions = true;
        this.numberOfCrossSections = 6;
        this.crossSections = [];
        this.crossSectionSpacing = 7;
        this.parentScene = parentScene;

        console.log("BUILD A BULLET");

        this.bulletTip = "img/bullet-tip.png";
        this.bulletBase = "img/bullet-end.png";

        if(projectiletype == "grenade"){
            this.bulletTip = "img/bullet-grenade-tip.png";
            this.bulletBase = "img/bullet-grenade-end.png";
        }

        this.spr = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(this.bulletTip);
        this.spr.anchor.x = this.spr.anchor.y = .5;
        this.gravity = gravity;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.alpha = 0;
        this.xVel = this.velocity * vector.x;
        this.zVel = this.velocity * vector.z;
        this.yVel = this.velocity * vector.y;
        var tipSection0 = new perspective.EditablePerspectiveObject(parentScene, x, y, z, .16);
        tipSection0.addChild(this.spr);
        this.parentScene.addPerspectiveObject(tipSection0);
        this.crossSections.push(tipSection0);
        var tipSection = new perspective.EditablePerspectiveObject(parentScene, x, y, z, .16);
        var sprTip = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(this.bulletTip);
        sprTip.anchor.x = sprTip.anchor.y = .5;
        tipSection.addChild(sprTip);
        this.parentScene.addPerspectiveObject(tipSection);
        this.crossSections.push(tipSection);
        for(var i = 0; i < this.numberOfCrossSections; i++) {
            var crossSection = new perspective.EditablePerspectiveObject(parentScene, x, y, z, .16);
            this.spr = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(this.bulletBase);
            this.spr.anchor.x = this.spr.anchor.y = .5;
            crossSection.addChild(this.spr);
            this.parentScene.addPerspectiveObject(crossSection);
            this.crossSections.push(crossSection);
        }
    }
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.getPosition = function () {
        return new MathK.Vector3(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.zPos);
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.getNextPosition = function () {
        return new MathK.Vector3(this.xPos + this.xVel * 3, this.yPos + this.yVel * 3, this.zPos + this.zVel * 3);
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.reset = function (x, y, z, localScale, velocity, gravity, vector, projectiletype) {
        if (typeof x === "undefined") { x = 0; }
        if (typeof y === "undefined") { y = 0; }
        if (typeof z === "undefined") { z = 0; }
        if (typeof localScale === "undefined") { localScale = 1; }
        if (typeof velocity === "undefined") { velocity = 100; }
        if (typeof gravity === "undefined") { gravity = 0; }
        if (typeof vector === "undefined") { vector = MathK.Vector3.zero; }
        this.isDead = false;
        this.isRebounding = false;
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
        this.zPos = z;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.gravity = gravity;
        this.xVel = this.velocity * vector.x;
        this.zVel = this.velocity * vector.z;
        this.yVel = this.velocity * vector.y;

    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.positionCrossSections = function () {
        var velVectorMagnitude = Math.sqrt(this.xVel * this.xVel + this.yVel * this.yVel + this.zVel * this.zVel);
        var offsetVelX = this.isRebounding ? this.reboundingVelX : this.xVel / velVectorMagnitude;
        var offsetVelZ = this.isRebounding ? this.reboundingVelZ : this.zVel / velVectorMagnitude;
        for(var i = 1; i <= this.crossSections.length; i++) {
            var crossSection = this.crossSections[i - 1];
            crossSection.xPos = this.xPos + this.crossSectionSpacing * i * -(offsetVelX);
            crossSection.yPos = this.yPos - this.crossSectionSpacing * i * (this.yVel / velVectorMagnitude);
            crossSection.zPos = this.zPos + this.crossSectionSpacing * i * (-Math.abs(offsetVelZ));
            if(crossSection.yPos > 0) {
                crossSection.yPos = 0;
            }
        }
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.rebound = function () {
        if(!this.isRebounding) {
            this.isRebounding = true;
            var velVectorMagnitude = Math.sqrt(this.xVel * this.xVel + this.yVel * this.yVel + this.zVel * this.zVel);
            this.reboundingVelX = this.xVel / velVectorMagnitude;
            this.reboundingVelZ = this.zVel / velVectorMagnitude;
        }
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.die = function () {
        if(!this.isDead) {
            this.isDead = true;
        }
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.hitBarrier = function () {
        this.xVel *= -.1;
        this.zVel *= -.1;
        this.rebound();
        this.die();
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.update = function () {
        _super.prototype.update.call(this);
        if(this.zPos > 2000) {
            this.zPos = 2000;
            this.hitBarrier();
        }
        this.yVel += this.gravity;
        this.xPos += this.xVel;
        this.yPos += this.yVel;
        this.zPos += this.zVel;
        if(this.yPos > 0) {
            this.yPos = 0;
            if(!this.isRebounding && this.xPos < 1500) {
                this.yVel *= -.5;
                this.xVel *= .5;
                this.zVel *= .5;
            } else {
                this.yVel *= -.3;
                this.xVel *= -.1;
                this.zVel *= -.1;
                this.rebound();
            }
            if(Math.abs(this.yVel) < .001) {
                this.die();
                return;
            }
        }
        this.positionCrossSections();
        this.velocity *= this.drag;
        this.positionCrossSections();
    };
    return TestProjectileVector;
})(perspective.EditablePerspectiveObject);
```

Comment: What if there is a way of destroying bullets that have been in existence for say 10 seconds. How do I remove bullets from the view?

Comment: I've tried many things - but I have not found a way of destroying pre-existing bullet objects or removing the textures from the stage

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the projectile code that handles a constructor to create the bullet, a reset function that puts the x,y,z coordinates back at the tip of the gun ready to recycle the bullet again.

I've not seen anything that could be used to create an infinite number of bullets - so they are skinned correctly - but then destroy bullets that are old. So keep the last 20 bullets. I tried reskinning the bullet on the reset - which would be ideal but I wasn't able to reverse engineer the code in the constructor to do so properly.

```
var TestProjectileVector = (function (_super) {
    __extends(TestProjectileVector, _super);
    function TestProjectileVector(parentScene, x, y, z, localScale, velocity, gravity, vector, projectiletype) {
        if (typeof x === "undefined") { x = 0; }
        if (typeof y === "undefined") { y = 0; }
        if (typeof z === "undefined") { z = 0; }
        if (typeof localScale === "undefined") { localScale = 1; }
        if (typeof velocity === "undefined") { velocity = 100; }
        if (typeof gravity === "undefined") { gravity = 0; }
        if (typeof vector === "undefined") { vector = MathK.Vector3.zero; }
        if (typeof projectiletype === "undefined") { projectiletype = "bullet"; }
        _super.call(this, parentScene, x, y, z, .13);
        this.verticalAngle = 0;
        this.horizontalAngle = 0;
        this.drag = .99;
        this.isDead = false;
        this.isRebounding = false;
        this.doCollisions = true;
        this.numberOfCrossSections = 6;
        this.crossSections = [];
        this.crossSectionSpacing = 7;
        this.parentScene = parentScene;

        console.log("BUILD A BULLET");

        this.bulletTip = "img/bullet-tip.png";
        this.bulletBase = "img/bullet-end.png";

        if(projectiletype == "grenade"){
            this.bulletTip = "img/bullet-grenade-tip.png";
            this.bulletBase = "img/bullet-grenade-end.png";
        }

        this.spr = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(this.bulletTip);
        this.spr.anchor.x = this.spr.anchor.y = .5;
        this.gravity = gravity;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.alpha = 0;
        this.xVel = this.velocity * vector.x;
        this.zVel = this.velocity * vector.z;
        this.yVel = this.velocity * vector.y;
        var tipSection0 = new perspective.EditablePerspectiveObject(parentScene, x, y, z, .16);
        tipSection0.addChild(this.spr);
        this.parentScene.addPerspectiveObject(tipSection0);
        this.crossSections.push(tipSection0);
        var tipSection = new perspective.EditablePerspectiveObject(parentScene, x, y, z, .16);
        var sprTip = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(this.bulletTip);
        sprTip.anchor.x = sprTip.anchor.y = .5;
        tipSection.addChild(sprTip);
        this.parentScene.addPerspectiveObject(tipSection);
        this.crossSections.push(tipSection);
        for(var i = 0; i < this.numberOfCrossSections; i++) {
            var crossSection = new perspective.EditablePerspectiveObject(parentScene, x, y, z, .16);
            this.spr = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(this.bulletBase);
            this.spr.anchor.x = this.spr.anchor.y = .5;
            crossSection.addChild(this.spr);
            this.parentScene.addPerspectiveObject(crossSection);
            this.crossSections.push(crossSection);
        }
    }
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.getPosition = function () {
        return new MathK.Vector3(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.zPos);
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.getNextPosition = function () {
        return new MathK.Vector3(this.xPos + this.xVel * 3, this.yPos + this.yVel * 3, this.zPos + this.zVel * 3);
    }; 

    TestProjectileVector.prototype.reset = function (x, y, z, localScale, velocity, gravity, vector, projectiletype) {
        if (typeof x === "undefined") { x = 0; }
        if (typeof y === "undefined") { y = 0; }
        if (typeof z === "undefined") { z = 0; }
        if (typeof localScale === "undefined") { localScale = 1; }
        if (typeof velocity === "undefined") { velocity = 100; }
        if (typeof gravity === "undefined") { gravity = 0; }
        if (typeof vector === "undefined") { vector = MathK.Vector3.zero; }
        this.isDead = false;
        this.isRebounding = false;
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
        this.zPos = z;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.gravity = gravity;
        this.xVel = this.velocity * vector.x;
        this.zVel = this.velocity * vector.z;
        this.yVel = this.velocity * vector.y;

    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.positionCrossSections = function () {
        var velVectorMagnitude = Math.sqrt(this.xVel * this.xVel + this.yVel * this.yVel + this.zVel * this.zVel);
        var offsetVelX = this.isRebounding ? this.reboundingVelX : this.xVel / velVectorMagnitude;
        var offsetVelZ = this.isRebounding ? this.reboundingVelZ : this.zVel / velVectorMagnitude;
        for(var i = 1; i <= this.crossSections.length; i++) {
            var crossSection = this.crossSections[i - 1];
            crossSection.xPos = this.xPos + this.crossSectionSpacing * i * -(offsetVelX);
            crossSection.yPos = this.yPos - this.crossSectionSpacing * i * (this.yVel / velVectorMagnitude);
            crossSection.zPos = this.zPos + this.crossSectionSpacing * i * (-Math.abs(offsetVelZ));
            if(crossSection.yPos > 0) {
                crossSection.yPos = 0;
            }
        }
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.rebound = function () {
        if(!this.isRebounding) {
            this.isRebounding = true;
            var velVectorMagnitude = Math.sqrt(this.xVel * this.xVel + this.yVel * this.yVel + this.zVel * this.zVel);
            this.reboundingVelX = this.xVel / velVectorMagnitude;
            this.reboundingVelZ = this.zVel / velVectorMagnitude;
        }
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.die = function () {
        if(!this.isDead) {
            this.isDead = true;

            /*
            var that = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                that.zPos = -999;
            }, 12000);*/
        }
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.hitBarrier = function () {
        this.xVel *= -.1;
        this.zVel *= -.1;
        this.rebound();
        this.die();
    };
    TestProjectileVector.prototype.update = function () {
        _super.prototype.update.call(this);
        if(this.zPos > 2000) {
            this.zPos = 2000;
            this.hitBarrier();
        }
        this.yVel += this.gravity;
        this.xPos += this.xVel;
        this.yPos += this.yVel;
        this.zPos += this.zVel;
        if(this.yPos > 0) {
            this.yPos = 0;
            if(!this.isRebounding && this.xPos < 1500) {
                this.yVel *= -.5;
                this.xVel *= .5;
                this.zVel *= .5;
            } else {
                this.yVel *= -.3;
                this.xVel *= -.1;
                this.zVel *= -.1;
                this.rebound();
            }
            if(Math.abs(this.yVel) < .001) {
                this.die();
                return;
            }
        }
        this.positionCrossSections();
        this.velocity *= this.drag;
        this.positionCrossSections();
    };
    return TestProjectileVector;
})(perspective.EditablePerspectiveObject);
```

Comment: I've tried taking the current crossSection array - looping through it and then try to remove those elements from the perspective using this found function -         var lastBulletSpriteObjs = this.crossSections;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.numberOfCrossSections; i++) {
            this.parentScene.removePerspectiveObject(lastBulletSpriteObjs[i]);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this - by picking up the length of current cross sections - then removing them from the array and perspective.

Then re-applying the textures again.

```
//__remove last skins
var lastBulletSpriteObjs = this.crossSections;
if(lastBulletSpriteObjs.length > 0){
    console.log("lastBulletSpriteObjs", lastBulletSpriteObjs);
    console.log("lastBulletSpriteObjs.length", lastBulletSpriteObjs.length);

    for(var i = 0; i < lastBulletSpriteObjs.length; i++) {
        this.parentScene.removePerspectiveObject(lastBulletSpriteObjs[i]);
    }
}

this.crossSections = [];//nulify the crossSections array
```